# Удалить часть строки из списка

Tags: c#, list

Получаю Excel файл из сторонней программы. Читаю Excel, получаю список из ячеек.

Мне необходимо полученные данные из ячейки проанализировать и удалить часть текста, которая не нужна. Но проблема вся в том, что никак не могу найти точку разделения, данные в каждой ячейки могут быть разные, но мне всегда нужно брать вторую часть. Может кто сталкивался с подобным.
Вот пример списка который я получаю из Excel

```
[0] ОСТ/OST 34-10-416-90 Труба/Pipe   18x2.5
[1] ОСТ/OST 34-10-420-90 Отвод/Bend С 90° 18x2.5-100x100-357-2.5
[2] по типу АМ20381-15-00.1 3СIIIс АРМК 3742.10 201 ТУ/TU Клапан сильфонный запорный ручной / manual shut-off bellows valve с замк. DN 15 Pp/Po 1 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
[3] A00 123-0040/250-200-01 3СIIIв ТУ/TU 29.13-MSA-118/03-IND Задвижка клиновая с э/пр / wedge gate valve with electric actuator DN 200 Pp/Po 2.5 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
[4] 28 ОСТ/OST 24.125.24-89 Фланец/Flange 50
[5] 01 ОСТ/OST 34-10-418-90 Отвод/Bend С 90° -57x5-2.5
[6] У26161-100М1-21 3СIIIс ТУ/TU 26-07-573-98 Клапан запорный/Stop valve ручной с замк. DN 100 Pp/Po 1.6 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
[7] по типу 1503-300-Э-Т3 3СIIIв ТУ/TU 37-041-05015348-2004 Задвижка с э/пр / gate valve with electric actuator DN 300 Pp/Po 2.5 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
[8] A00 123-0040/250-200-01 3СIIIв ТУ/TU 29.13-MSA-118/03-IND Задвижка клиновая с э/пр / wedge gate valve with electric actuator DN 200 Pp/Po 2.5 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
```

А вот как мне нужно получить на выходе

```
[0] Труба/Pipe   18x2.5
[1] Отвод/Bend С 90° 18x2.5-100x100-357-2.5
[2] Клапан сильфонный запорный ручной / manual shut-off bellows valve с замк. DN 15 Pp/Po 1 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
[3] Задвижка клиновая с э/пр / wedge gate valve with electric actuator DN 200 Pp/Po 2.5 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
[4] Фланец/Flange 50
[5] Отвод/Bend С 90° -57x5-2.5
[6] Клапан запорный/Stop valve ручной с замк. DN 100 Pp/Po 1.6 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
[7] Задвижка с э/пр / gate valve with electric actuator DN 300 Pp/Po 2.5 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
[8] Задвижка клиновая с э/пр / wedge gate valve with electric actuator DN 200 Pp/Po 2.5 MPa Tp/To 250 °С
```

Как вариант я вижу создать список с основными ключевыми словами, которые я смогу предугадать и по ним фильтровать. Но может есть более универсальный вариант?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: как эти данные располагаются в ячейках исходной таблицы и как вы их оттуда читаете?

Comment: Если в excel каждая строка данных не разбита по столбцам, то это почти невозможно. Почему почти? Потому что необходимо будет написать свой анализатор строк, который будет на основе "некоторых знаний" парсить вашу строку. Вся сложность будет в формировании этих знаний. Нужно четкое правило разделения строк по группам.

Comment: Данные располагаются по столбцам, например данные которые в примере располагаются в стобце "С" и идут вниз по строкам,  то есть в экселе каждый элемент списка это отдельная ячейка. Нипример в эксель они начинаются с 5 строки и идут вниз (C5, C6, C7...)

Читаю данные с помощью NPOI, так как там файлы .xls

Comment: т.е. приведенные строки хранятся в ячейках exel в точно таком же монолитном виде? Тогда действительно простого способа нет, да и надежного сложного способа тоже не очень есть. Нужен полноценный анализ строки на основе некоторых знаний, т.к. данные не структурированы. А вариант зайти с другой стороны и подправить выгрузку в excel не подойдет? Сдается мне это будет дешевле, чем создавать "умный" парсер для простого импорта данных.